# how to send file from Windows-CE to PC Through Socket

Tags: c#, windows-ce

how to send file from Windows-CE to PC Through Socket

(and from PC to Windows-CE)

can i get any sample C# code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Transferring a file through a socket is, in general, OS agnostic so the "Windows CE" part of the question doesn't matter much.  You'll need both code for sending and code for receiving.  Nicely enough there are plenty of examples online for doing this.  [Here's one](http://socketprogramming.blogspot.com/2007/11/file-transfer-using-c-socket.html).  [Here's another](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/10/client-server-simple-file-sharing-and-file-transfer/). [And yet another](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SocketApplication.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that the easiest way might be to do it via FTP, since then you can just install any FTP server on the PC and don't have to worry about it at all.

So looking at the [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) Class it says that it's supported by Windows CE. Combine that with the [FTP RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) and then do a google search for "[C# ftp client](http://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHNQ_en-GBGB395GB407&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c#%20ftp%20client)" and you should have enough to get you started.

This seems to be a library that might have all that code written for you already: [OpenNETCF FTP Library](http://ftp.codeplex.com/)